# Rails Change Default Projects Database 'sqllite' to PostgreSql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm learning ruby. I've created some application and played with it.

i wanted to change the database to postgres. I modified gemfile with

```
gem 'pg'
```

[pg already installed in usr/bin/pg]
then update database.yml with 
postgresql where sqllite is used.

pg connection bad:

```
FATAL: role "user" does not exist
```

i've created some postgres user already. what should i have to change to work with postgres?

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/development.postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

user:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/test.postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/production.postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: what's your database.yml content, is there username: user..? if yes then have u created a role in  postgres with name user

Comment: is the user named 'user' 'll be crated? or should it be existing one?

Comment: remove username from your database.yaml file and password too if present...

Comment: otherwise if u want to use specific user, then u need to create it first in postgresql

Comment: the yaml content is only what i've posted. [using postgresql i've created user but how to use that?] where is my rails accessing it?

Comment: when i run rake db:setup it shows error cannot create user!

Comment: m sorry little confused now, are you talking about database role "user" or a table named "user" in your databse

Comment: and yes one thing is missing in yml file..host: localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a username to connect to PostgreSQL as, `libpq` will connect using the *login username of the current running user*.

`libpq` is what the `Pg` gem used by Rails uses to connect to PostgreSQL.

So, in your `database.yml`, specify the PostgreSQL user to connect to the database as with a `user:` entry. Make sure this corresponds to a user that exists in PostgreSQL, and that `pg_hba.conf` permits this user to connect.

To learn more, see the [client authentication chapter of the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/client-authentication.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know its a two year old question, but I just ran into the same problem, and i fixed it by changing the syntax of config.yml, then I rake db:migrate

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: 5

development:
<<: *default
database: yourappnamehere_development


test:
<<: *default
database: yourappnamehere_testdevelopment:


production:
<<: *default
database: YOURAPPNAME_production
username: YOURUSERNAME
password: <%= ENV['YOURAPPNAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```